# JSP search option

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

i have been trying to make it work for a long time now. but none of the reference works. so far these are my latest code regarding search. hopefully someone can help. i am new in jsp and this is final graduation project. so badly need help.

`code`:

index.jsp:

```
<div class="container">
<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="search.jsp">
<input type="text" name="roll_no" class="form-control" placeholder="Search roll no..">
<button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</form>
```

search.jsp:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String database = "hospital";
String userid = "hospital";
String password = "hospital";
String NAME=request.getParameter("NAME");
try {
Class.forName(driver);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Search Data</h1>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>CODE</td>
<td>NAME</td>
<td>PRICE</td>
</tr>
<%
try{
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl+database, userid, password);
statement=connection.createStatement();
String sql ="select * from product where NAME="+NAME+"' ";
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
while(resultSet.next()){
%>
<tr>
<td><%=resultSet.getString("CODE") %></td>
<td><%=resultSet.getString("NAME") %></td>
<td><%=resultSet.getString("PRICE") %></td>
</tr>
<%
}
connection.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your <form> you have input with `name="roll_no"` and your are getting it in your jsp page using using `request.getParameter("NAME")` this should be `request.getParameter("roll_no")` change it and check onces,

Comment: did that...still no response....

Comment: does your table have data with value which you are sending from inputs ,Also what doesn't work please elaborate it more?

Comment: yes the SQL tables have the given data. the program is supposed to call from the utility file and return search through the home page. i have methods inside utils for CRUD but no matter how i try i cannot make the search function to work through the utils. so i tried calling it outside the utils fiiles. but still it gives error

Comment: what error did you got ? edit your question and add that as well.